# Minimal-length strings which are substrings of no string in a given CFL

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Is there an algorithm for enumerating a sequence of minimal-length substrings composed of terminal symbols within some CFG which are not substrings of any string in the language defined by that CFG? In other words, given a CFG, $G=(V,\Sigma ,R,S)$, find a sequence of increasing-length strings $E = \{e \in \Sigma^+ \mid \forall \sigma \in \mathcal{L}_G, e$ is not a substring of $\sigma\}$.

Comment: Do you have a proof that $E$ is guaranteed to be finite?  Don't you want to specify $e \in \mathcal{L}_G$ rather than $e \in \Sigma^+$?

Comment: $E$ may infinite, but in practice we only care about short strings $E \cap \Sigma^k$ where $k$ is some small number. Re: "Don't you want to specify $e \in \mathcal{L}_G$..."
 No. $e$ must be excluded from every substring of every string in $\mathcal{L}_G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach. Enumerate lengths in increasing order (length 0, length 1, length).  For each length, enumerate all strings in lexicographic order, as follows.

Let's take length 4 as illustration.  First, check whether any member of $L$ has any substring of the form `a???` (where `?` is a wildcard that can match any symbol).  If not, then you can output `aaaa`, `aaab`, ..., `azzz`, then move on to checking whether any member of $L$ has any substring of the form `b???`.  If yes, then move on to checking whether any member of $L$ has any substring of the form `aa??`.  Repeat iteratively.  In this way, you walk through possible prefixes in lexicographic order, in a breadth-first manner.

How do you check whether any member of $L$ has any substring of the form `a???`?  This amounts to testing whether there is any string in both $L$ and $\Sigma^* a \Sigma^3 \Sigma^*$, i.e., whether $L \cap \Sigma^* a \Sigma^3 \Sigma^* \ne \emptyset$.  Note that $L$ is context-free and $\Sigma^* a \Sigma^3 \Sigma^*$ is regular, so their intersection is context-free (and you can easily construct a PDA or context-free grammar for it using standard methods), and thus you can test whether it generates a non-empty language (using standard methods).  Each check will take about $O(|G| \ell^2)$ time, where $|G|$ is the size of the context-free grammar $G$ for $L$ and $\ell$ is the length of strings you are enumerating.

Comment: Thank you! Your algorithm seems to be viable, although I have not yet implemented it, because computing the intersection between a CFL and regular grammar is somewhat nontrivial in the presence of ε (cf. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.06809.pdf).
I recently learned that Osorio and Navarro (2001) have another algorithm decides whether a given string is a substring of any string in a CFL, which considers not only the prefix, but also the infix and suffix cases. It seems somewhat more easy to implement: https://nokyotsu.com/me/papers/cic01.pdf

Comment: @breandan, I think it's easy to build a finite-state automaton that represents a regular language like $\Sigma^* a \Sigma^3 \Sigma^*$ (for instance, you can build a NFA, then convert to a DFA with the powerset construction; or you can construct a DFA directly), and then easy to intersect with a pushdown automaton for $L$.